# Display text in a specific position with imgNotes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using in my webpage imgNotes to display tooltip on backgroud image. It does work.
Now I want also to add a simple text in a specific position without using the popup.
I would like to use the same coordinate that I'm using for imgNotes("addNote").

Could you help me?

Thank you and regards

Pasquale

Answer (score 1):

I solved my task; I've added a new function before addNote in the imgNotes.js file.

```
/*
 *  Add a text
 */
addText: function(relx, rely, text) {
    var self = this;
    var elem = $(document.createElement('span')).html(text);    
    var $elem = $(elem);
    $(this.img).imgViewer("addElem",elem);
    $elem.data("relx", relx).data("rely", rely);

    switch (this.options.vAll) {
        case "top": $elem.data("yOffset", 0); break;
        case "bottom": $elem.data("yOffset", $elem.height()); break;
        default: $elem.data("yOffset", Math.round($elem.height()/2));
    }
    switch (this.options.hAll) {
        case "left": $elem.data("xOffset", 0); break;
        case "right": $elem.data("xOffset", $elem.width()); break;
        default: $elem.data("xOffset", Math.round($elem.width()/2));
    }

    this.notes.push(elem);
    $(this.img).imgViewer("update");
    return elem;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the text is in the right position in Chrome but not for FireFox.